# Any difference between "as to" and "about"?

Tags: prepositions

Are these two expressions interchangeable? Or is there an important difference?
example sentence:

> Everyone was curious as to why Mark was leaving.

> Everyone was curious about why Mark was leaving.

Answer (score 3):

There are **very, very few** words or phrases in English that are entirely interchangeable – each word and phrase has its own nuance.

When speaking any language, people include intonation and gestures to add meaning.

Thus,  **as to** and **about** are not fully interchangeable in all cases: As to is a **free** modifier that modifies the main clause as a whole, about is a **bound** modifier that modifies the last substantive.

1. A: I have ***explained*** the manufacturing process – as to the storage, I will leave that (i.e. the ***explanation* of the storage**) to Mr Smith. (correct)
2. A: I have explained the manufacturing process – *about the storage, I will leave that (i.e. the ***storage***)  to Mr Smith. (wrong)

You will note the referent of “that” in 2 is storage

**As to X** = **as far as the subject of X is concerned; to the extent that the subject of X is concerned**

**About X** = **on the subject of X**

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are interchangeable and there aren't big differences between the two.
 However, I prefer using *about*, because for me is more informal, but you could have used both.

Here you have a deeper explanation of the little differences that there are between those two:

[differences between "as to" and "about"](https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/difference-between-as-to-and-about/#:%7E:text=When%20about%20is%20used%20to,he%20stole%20from%20his%20parents.)

Comment: Yes, they are interchangeable _in this context_. However, you should mention that there are contexts where they are not (as shown in your linked article).

Comment: yep, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: “As to* acts as a retrospective pointer (to the previous sentence or clause). *The war has begun. As to the future, I can say little hopeful.*